# New figure in Latexdiff

Tags: latexdiff

I am using [`latexdiff`](http://ctan.org/pkg/latexdiff) to compare two tex files. In some places I have new figures and `latexdiff` puts its comments inside the `includegraphics` command and then the diffed file won't compile.

Example:

```
\includegraphics[ width=0.7\columnwidth,keepaspectratio] {\DIFaddFL{Figures/I3D_MBU.pdf}}
```

How can I include images in the diff?

Comment: I have edited your question to (hopefully!) make it a little more clear. Please feel free to [edit it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/223308/edit) yourself if you feel I've messed something up. Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the space between the optional and filename argument in both old and new file (preferred solution)

Or use option --allow-spaces ; this can have some undesired side-effects, though.